# Trace logging using #define to avoid a performance issue

Tags: c++, performance

I have to trace log a very performance critical part of my application. And it has to be configurable in production.

I came up with this thing, but something about it seems like a bad idea.

```
#define TRACE(X) if(log->trace) {log->traceLog(X);}
```

The `log->trace` is a bool so it should be fairly cheap in branch prediction, it is going to be used something like this:

```
TRACE("Input channel: " + std::to_string(ChannelNumber) + " [r] " +
          std::to_string(ChannelValue->LongReal))
```

Creating a string and converting all sorts of stuff to log is expensive and a log method call which would check inside if trace log level is disabled would do just that.

Is there a better way to doing this? Am I approaching trace logging entirely in a wrong way?

Comment: Looks fine to me. The expensive parts are ignored if `log->trace` is false. No need to have `traceLog()` check `trace` internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine in production.

And the define is easy to look up, so there is not much confusion when reading the code.